# Flex - change and focusOut in one event?

Tags: apache-flex

I need to be able to trigger an event on change, but only when user focus out of the input text.
Is there any one event I can use?

I guess I can use a combination of both, by finding out which of them triggers last, and only use that, if the other has been called, but that introduces some complexity and clutters the code.

Comment: Change and FocusOut are two distinct events.  It sounds to me like you're trying to "something on FocusOut, but only if the text has changed since FocusIn".

Comment: @Brian Yes that is what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no single event that combines both of these concepts.  You'll need to write some custom logic to do what you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

Using the mx.managers.FocusManager *getFocus()* method you can find the component that currently has focus. In the change handler on the TextInput you can check if this TextInput currently is the component with focus. If not, you can go about your business.